# Meaning of `process` in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the part of dialog from the movie:

> Sometimes I wonder, if all the time that was given to me was like 16 milliseconds... And I had no past memory, had nothing carved in my mind before those 16 milliseconds. The only thing that was left imprinted into my brain were the images, and the smells, the feelings of those 16 milliseconds...
> **How do you think I would process that?**

A man in the front says:

> I think you life would be exactly as long as someone who lived for 100 years...

I can't get the meaning of *process* in this context. Could you please explain me the meaning of the highlighted phrase.

Comment: Have you looked up the verb 'process' in a good dictionary?

Comment: I can not understand how that relates to the answer of living for 100 years.

Comment: It does not directly relate to living for 100 years. The first speaker is talking about how to think about, or cope with, the knowledge of having 16 thousandths of 1 second to live, but with a blank brain. The "man in front" seems to be saying that living for that very short period is the same, in some unexplained way, as living for 100 years. This is either profound or stupid, depending on your point of view. Movie dialog is sometimes profound, but more often stupid. Maybe the character is meant to be stoned on marijuana or some other drug.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, why did I get the negative mark? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Whoever gave the down vote is anonymous, and did not have to give a reason.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, anyway thanks for your explanation. I should add that English is not my native language... that's the reason of such misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process something (verb) is to subject it to a a step, or series of steps, to reach a finished product or state. We process flour, yeast, and water to make bread. The verb has come to be used about mental states or processes, to mean 'think about', 'digest', 'understand', 'absorb', 'cope with', 'deal with', etc. Especially it is used to mean:

> to think about a difficult or sad situation so that you can gradually
> accept it

[Process (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/process)

Comment: Given that the brain cannot process very much other than simple tasks in less than about 100 milliseconds, I think that nothing very much is going to happen in the situation outlined in the question, especially considering that the person has "nothing" "carved in" his or her brain, presumably including the thinking skills acquired during very early life. You might as well ask how a person, having seen the flash of the gun, can "process" the knowledge that a bullet will enter their skull in an instant.

Comment: 16 milliseconds is not a lot of time to 'gradually' accept something mentally or emotionally. There are 62.5 such periods in 1 second.